# How to disable different face for empty lines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, customization, spacemacs

In my Emacs, I have different face for empty lines with space/tab characters. How can I disable it?

[image]

This cause lot of distraction when trying to navigate through someone else's code which I cannot modify.

I would appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Comment: That is not the default Emacs behavior. Dunno whether it is the default Spacemacs behavior. If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what you are doing to cause it. A guess is that you are using `whitespace-mode`. If so, see its doc for how to turn this behavior off or otherwise specialize it.

Comment: `M-x describe-mode` will list out the major and all the minor modes, if you share that, we might could point you to the culprit.